# How to convert character to factor levels for an entire data set

Tags: r

Using the adult data set as an example, the character values can be converted to factors like this:

```
adult <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/InfiniteCuriosity/templatedemo/main/Adult.csv')

library(tidyverse)
df <- mutate_if(adult, is.character, as.factor)
```

That will convert the character columns to a factors. I don't see a way to convert those factors to factor levels. The warning in ?factor states, "To transform a factor f to approximately its original numeric values, as.numeric(levels(f))[f] is recommended and slightly more efficient than as.numeric(as.character(f))", but I don't see a way to do that for all of the columns with factors in a data set, such as the adult data set. I can convert them to numbers, but not factor levels.

The conversion to numbers is:

```
df <- mutate_if(df, is.factor, as.numeric)
```

If I try as.numeric(levels(df))[df], as suggested by ?as.factor, that returns the error:

```
Error in as.numeric(levels(df))[df] : invalid subscript type 'closure'
```

Comment: `mutate_if` has been superseded since Jan 2019, I suggest learning and shifting to `across(..)` as its help page recommends.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `factor levels`? To me, the "levels" of a factor are the _character_ values that were originally encoded into factors (stored as integers). For instance, if we do `factor(c("A","A","A","Z"))` then the factor levels are `c("A","Z")` (typically not the same length as the original data). Looking at `adult$sex`, for instance, what is your desired end-result? Is it `c(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, ...)`?

Comment: The issue with `as.numeric(levels(df))[df]` is that you are running this function intended for a single factor column on `df`, the whole data frame. `mutate_if(df, is.factor, as.numeric)` applies the function `as.numeric` to individual columns within the data frame, not the data frame as a whole. You can put other functions there, like `mutate_if(df, is.factor, nchar)` if you wanted the number of characters in the word. You can also use custom "anonymous" functions that you define in-line, like `mutate_if(df, is.factor, function(f) as.numeric(levels(f))[f])`. Syntactically, that should work.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I will fix the code to show across(), and I will check other in-line  functions to return levels when I get home. This looks good!

Comment: >Looking at adult$sex, for instance, what is your desired end-result? Is it c(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, ...)?
Exactly, yes, that's correct, but doing it for all the levels in all the factors in a data set,  not just one feature. I'm still working on getting that to run successfully, but this is much closer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `type.convert` setting `as.is=FALSE`.

```
> adult <- type.convert(adult, as.is=FALSE)
> str(adult)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ X             : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ age           : int  50 38 53 28 37 49 52 31 42 37 ...
 $ workclass     : Factor w/ 7 levels " ?"," Federal-gov",..: 6 4 4 4 4 4 6 4 4 4 ...
 $ fnlwgt        : int  83311 215646 234721 338409 284582 160187 209642 45781 159449 280464 ...
 $ education     : Factor w/ 13 levels " 10th"," 11th",..: 8 10 2 8 11 5 10 11 8 13 ...
 $ education_num : int  13 9 7 13 14 5 9 14 13 10 ...
 $ marital_status: Factor w/ 6 levels " Divorced"," Married-AF-spouse",..: 3 1 3 3 3 4 3 5 3 3 ...
 $ occupation    : Factor w/ 13 levels " ?"," Adm-clerical",..: 4 6 6 9 4 8 4 9 4 4 ...
 $ relationship  : Factor w/ 6 levels " Husband"," Not-in-family",..: 1 2 1 6 6 2 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ race          : Factor w/ 5 levels " Amer-Indian-Eskimo",..: 5 5 3 3 5 3 5 5 5 3 ...
 $ sex           : Factor w/ 2 levels " Female"," Male": 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ capital_gain  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14084 5178 0 ...
 $ capital_loss  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ hours_per_week: int  13 40 40 40 40 16 45 50 40 80 ...
 $ native_country: Factor w/ 10 levels " ?"," Cuba"," England",..: 10 10 10 2 10 6 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ income        : Factor w/ 2 levels " <=50K"," >50K": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
```